# Принцип DIP: абстракции и композиция

Tags: php, ооп, dependency-injection, solid

Как гласит принцип DIP из SOLID:

> Абстракции не должны зависеть от деталей. Детали должны зависеть от абстракций.

Следуя из этого определения, мне казалось, что любая зависимость должна быть через интерфейс или абстрактный класс.

В одном из ответов с SO, писали, что это не совсем так.

Но никакого пояснения и примеров небыло.

Хотелось,чтобы кто-то объяснил, в каких случаях необходимо при реализации деталей нужно оперировать интерфейсами и абстрактными классами, а в каких не имееь смысла.

И всегда ли нужно аргументы-зависимости указывать от интерфейса или абстрактного класса?

Если можно, с примера :)

И второй вопрос, связан с видом ассоциации - композицией, а именно:
когда мы создаём объект внутри конструктора, но при этом не внедряем его - нарушает ли это принцип DIP? Т.к. у нас зависимость жёсткая. Также не зависит от абстракции..  и так же не понятно, как тестировать такой класс в котором есть композиция..  поясните пожалуйста, желательно с примерами.

Comment: Возможно я оставлял комментарий в прошлом вашем вопросе. Приведу жизненные пример. Есть интерфейс `IDatabase`. Он проходит как зависимость во всех классов, использующих соединение с базой данных. В контейнере зависимости я прописываю, что при нахождении зависимости `IDatabase` разрешать её классов `CurrentDatabase`, который реализует интерфейс `IDatabase`. Если мне нужно будет сменить реализацию, то я просто укажу в контейнере использовать другой класс. Нигде в другом месте ничего менять не нужно.

Comment: Если вы создаёте композицию жестко в конструкторе, то вы нарушаете принцип. Во-первых, вы не можете переопределить реализацию кроме как переписыванием конструктора. Во-вторых, вы зависите от конкретной реализации, а не от абстракции. В случае смены реализации вам опять нужно будет переписывать конструктор